# Apache Http Client 4 Form Post Multi-part data

Tags: java, groovy, multipartform-data, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to post some form parameters to a server through an HTTP request (one of which is a file). So I use Apache HTTP Client like so...

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlStr);

params = []
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "bond"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "vesper"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file", payload));

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");

CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

The server returns an error, stack trace is..

```
the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:954)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:331)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:351)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:156)
```

I understand from other posts that I need to somehow come up with a boundary, which is a string not found in the content. But how do I create this boundary in the code I have above? Should it be another parameter? Just a code sample is what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accepted gustf's answer because it got rid of the exception I was having and so I thought I was on the right track, but it was not complete. The below is what I did to finally get it to work...

```
File payload = new File("/Users/CasinoRoyaleBank")
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );
entity.addPart( "file", new FileBody(payload))
entity.addPart( "username", new StringBody("bond"))
entity.addPart( "password", new StringBody("vesper"))
httpPost.setEntity( entity );
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: Ok, i see. Sorry about that, but when you accepted the answer I assumed that it was working for you. I will update my answer with your findings.

Comment: Hi again, I now updated the answer with an equivalent code that uses the builder. I also checked the differences from the original code which is: 1) Putting `addPart("file", new FileBody(payload)` before other parts. 2) The charset, it defaults to `ASCII` in the deprecated constructor in your code. And in my original is defaults to `ISO_8859_1`. This should normally not be any problems so my idea is that  it is the first which is also strange. But maybe this is the way `MultipartHttpServletRequest` works, I don't know. If you have the interest and time to test this, it would be great.

Answer (score 11):

As the exception says, you have not specified the "multipart boundary". This is a string that acts as a separator between the different parts in the request. But in you case it seems like you do not handle any different parts.

What you probably want to use is [MultipartEntityBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html) so you don't have to worry about how it all works under the hood.

It should be Ok to do the following

```
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlStr);

        File payload = new File("/Users/CasinoRoyaleBank");

        HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                .addBinaryBody("file", payload)
                .addTextBody("username", "bond")
                .addTextBody("password", "vesper")
                .build();
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

However, here is a version that should be compatible with @AbuMariam findings below but without the use of deprecated methods/constructors.

```
        File payload = new File("/Users/CasinoRoyaleBank");

        ContentType plainAsciiContentType = ContentType.create("text/plain", Consts.ASCII);
        HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                .addPart("file", new FileBody(payload))
                .addPart("username", new StringBody("bond", plainAsciiContentType))
                .addPart("password", new StringBody("vesper", plainAsciiContentType))
                .build();
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

The `UrlEncodedFormEntity` is normally not used for multipart, and it defaults to content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Your suggestion worked in that I no longer got the error. But on the sever side, when I am reading that data, I am doing..  MultipartHttpServletRequest multiRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
        CommonsMultipartFile file = (CommonsMultipartFile) multiRequest.getFile("file"); And file is coming out as null.

Comment: Updated the answer with respect to `builder.addBinaryBody(String, File)`. But I guess you already saw that one :)

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't have more upvoates, after searching for 2 hours lots of complicated solutions, this is simple and works like a charm. best answer for this topic on stackoverflow.